# Get object value and add them to HTML Div

Tags: javascript

I have a `taskObject` that includes values such as title of my task.

I would like to add the title of that task to the HTML Div but can't seem to find a way of getting the title on the `tasksManager.add.title` in order to obtain the value. The front-end result would be user to see which task they are doing on a certain day every time they log in the app.

Here's my code

```js
//Task Manager//

var idCounter = 0
var tasksManager = {
  array: [],
  add: function(task, bracketStart, bracketEnd, date) {
    taskObject = {
      title: task,
      idVerification: idCounter++,
      startTask: bracketStart,
      endTask: bracketEnd,
      dateTask: date
    }
    tasksManager.array.push(taskObject)
  },
  show: function(id) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < tasksManager.array.length; i++) {
      if (id === tasksManager.array[i].idVerification) {
        return tasksManager.array[i]
      }
    }
  },
  delete: function(task) {
    if (this.show) {
      tasksManager.array.splice(task)
    }
  }

}

// Calendar

var myDate = new Date(),
  year = myDate.getFullYear(),
  month = myDate.getMonth(),
  day = myDate.getDay(),
  date = myDate.getDate()

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
var dates = ["0", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st"]


var dayElement = document.createElement('div')
dayElement.innerHTML = days[day] + "," + " " + dates[date] + " " + "of" + " " + months[month] + " " + year
document.getElementById("month-today").appendChild(dayElement)

function removeClass() {
  document.getElementById('task-input').classList.toggle('new-task');
}

var button = document.getElementById("save-task");
var input = document.getElementById("add-new-task");
var startTime = document.getElementById("time-stamp");
var endTime = document.getElementById("time-stamp-finish");
var date = document.getElementById("event-date")
// -- - THIS IS MY ATTEMPT TO ADD THE OBJECT TITLE TO DIV-- -
var taskEvent = document.createElement('div')
taskEvent.innerHTML = tasksManager.array.add.title
document.getElementById("event-1").appendChild(taskEvent)


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  tasksManager.add(input.value, startTime.value, endTime.value, date.value);
  console.log(tasksManager.array)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ProdPlus </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tomorrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>ProdPlus+ </h1>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">

  </div>
  <div id="month-today"></div>
  <div id="day-today"></div>
  <div id="date-today"></div>


  <button class="add-task" onclick="removeClass()">Add task</button>

  <div class="new-task" id="task-input">
    <div>Task: <input id="add-new-task" type="text"></div>
    <div id="add-time">
      <label>Time</label>
      <select id="time-stamp">
        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      </select>
      -
      <select id="time-stamp-finish">
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="date-stamp">
      Date:
      <input type="date" id="event-date" name="bday" max="2030-12-31"><br>
    </div>
    <button class="save-task" id="save-task" onclick="">Save task</button>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar">
    <!-- <div class="month-indicator">
                <div>January</div>
                <div>February</div>
                <div>March</div>
                <div>April</div>
                <div>June</div>
                <div>July</div>
                <div>August</div>
                <div>September</div>
                <div>October</div>
                <div>November</div>
                <div>December</div>
         </div> -->
    <div class="day-of-week">
      <div class="day">Sunday</div>
      <div class="day">Monday</div>
      <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="day">Thursday</div>
      <div class="day">Friday</div>
      <div class="day">Saturday</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hours">
      <div>04:00</div>
      <div>05:00</div>
      <div>06:00</div>
      <div>07:00</div>
      <div>08:00</div>
      <div>09:00</div>
      <div>10:00</div>
      <div>11:00</div>
      <div>12:00</div>
      <div>13:00</div>
      <div>14:00</div>
      <div>15:00</div>
      <div>16:00</div>
      <div>17:00</div>
      <div>18:00</div>
      <div>19:00</div>
      <div>20:00</div>
      <div>21:00</div>
      <div>22:00</div>
      <div>23:00</div>
      <div>00:00</div>
      <div>01:00</div>
      <div>02:00</div>
      <div>03:00</div>

    </div>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="events">
        <div class="event" id="event-1"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dates">

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the append to inside the click AFTER the creation of the taskEvent

```js
//Task Manager//

var idCounter = 0
var tasksManager = {
  array: [],
  add: function(task, bracketStart, bracketEnd, date) {
    taskObject = {
      title: task,
      idVerification: idCounter++,
      startTask: bracketStart,
      endTask: bracketEnd,
      dateTask: date
    }
    tasksManager.array.push(taskObject)
  },
  show: function(id) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < tasksManager.array.length; i++) {
      if (id === tasksManager.array[i].idVerification) {
        return tasksManager.array[i]
      }
    }
  },
  delete: function(task) {
    if (this.show) {
      tasksManager.array.splice(task)
    }
  }

}

// Calendar

var myDate = new Date(),
  year = myDate.getFullYear(),
  month = myDate.getMonth(),
  day = myDate.getDay(),
  date = myDate.getDate()

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
var dates = ["0", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st", "1st"]


var dayElement = document.createElement('div')
dayElement.innerHTML = days[day] + "," + " " + dates[date] + " " + "of" + " " + months[month] + " " + year
document.getElementById("month-today").appendChild(dayElement)

function removeClass() {
  document.getElementById('task-input').classList.toggle('new-task');
}

var button = document.getElementById("save-task");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var input = document.getElementById("add-new-task");
  var startTime = document.getElementById("time-stamp");
  var endTime = document.getElementById("time-stamp-finish");
  var date = document.getElementById("event-date")
  var taskEvent = document.createElement('div')
  tasksManager.add(input.value, startTime.value, endTime.value, date.value);
  //console.log(tasksManager.array)
  taskEvent.innerHTML = tasksManager.array[tasksManager.array.length - 1].title
  document.getElementById("event-1").appendChild(taskEvent)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ProdPlus </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tomorrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>ProdPlus+ </h1>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">

  </div>
  <div id="month-today"></div>
  <div id="day-today"></div>
  <div id="date-today"></div>


  <button class="add-task" onclick="removeClass()">Add task</button>

  <div class="new-task" id="task-input">
    <div>Task: <input id="add-new-task" type="text"></div>
    <div id="add-time">
      <label>Time</label>
      <select id="time-stamp">
        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      </select>
      -
      <select id="time-stamp-finish">
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="date-stamp">
      Date:
      <input type="date" id="event-date" name="bday" max="2030-12-31"><br>
    </div>
    <button class="save-task" id="save-task" onclick="">Save task</button>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar">
    <!-- <div class="month-indicator">
                <div>January</div>
                <div>February</div>
                <div>March</div>
                <div>April</div>
                <div>June</div>
                <div>July</div>
                <div>August</div>
                <div>September</div>
                <div>October</div>
                <div>November</div>
                <div>December</div>
         </div> -->
    <div class="day-of-week">
      <div class="day">Sunday</div>
      <div class="day">Monday</div>
      <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="day">Thursday</div>
      <div class="day">Friday</div>
      <div class="day">Saturday</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hours">
      <div>04:00</div>
      <div>05:00</div>
      <div>06:00</div>
      <div>07:00</div>
      <div>08:00</div>
      <div>09:00</div>
      <div>10:00</div>
      <div>11:00</div>
      <div>12:00</div>
      <div>13:00</div>
      <div>14:00</div>
      <div>15:00</div>
      <div>16:00</div>
      <div>17:00</div>
      <div>18:00</div>
      <div>19:00</div>
      <div>20:00</div>
      <div>21:00</div>
      <div>22:00</div>
      <div>23:00</div>
      <div>00:00</div>
      <div>01:00</div>
      <div>02:00</div>
      <div>03:00</div>

    </div>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="events">
        <div class="event" id="event-1"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dates">

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```